# How to install pypy on debian wheezy

Tags: python, debian, pypy

I try to install pypy on server with debian 7.4. I tried few difference ways and all failed. When I added jessie main to sources.list I can install pypy and pypy-dev but for some reason new packages broke my postgres database. I think it's bad approach. 
My secound try is to build it from source. I created the same configuration in virtual machine using vagrant. When i login via ssh and run with sudo:

```
python /opt/pypy/rpython/bin/rpython --opt=jit /opt/pypy/pypy/goal/targetpypystandalone.py
```

after long time of specialized many blocks my ssh connection broken

Comment: The usual answer is using backports. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157. The build dependencies of the pypy in jessie do not look too bad; I think rebuilding it on wheezy would be possible. Also, you should use screen or tmux when working remotely on a server via ssh.

Answer (score 4):

I also tried many things to install pypy on debian but was unsuccesful,
so i switched to ubuntu. Now I was able to install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties software-properties-common -y -f
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pypy/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pypy -y
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential -y
```

Comment: Awesome! How about for Python 3 64 bit?

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson ... a bit late, to be sure, but ... `apt-get install -y pypy3` supports python-3.7.12 on ubuntu-20.04 ... I'm looking for the python-3.8 version ...

Answer (score 0):

See this
*Portable 32 and 64 bit x86 PyPy binaries for many Linux distributions*:
https://github.com/squeaky-pl/portable-pypy
(It's recommanded by the official site: http://www.pypy.org/download.html#installing )